# SSRS Chart and dates

Tags: visual-studio-2008, date, reporting-services, charts

I have a data set that contains a date and a number.  The dates are roughly a week apart, but this is not guaranteed.  I am trying to display the date as the Horizontal Axis label of a bar graph, but it keeps showing the dates in interval format.  I am using Visual Studio 2008.  I want it to be super simple.  I want an evenly spaced bar graph, that has a horizontal axis label with my date and the corresponding value.  If the dates are 2 to 3 weeks apart I still want the bars next to each other without any spacing.

I've tried converting the date to a string using Cstr() to get it to handle the date as just an arbitrary value.  I've tried playing with the interval settings.

I was going to post a screenshot of what I was working with, but I'm not allowed to yet, so I will try to describe them.

The one picture is of the format I'm looking for.

There are dates in the horizontal axis labels and for each date there is a corresponding bar above it with the value associated.  Each bar is evenly spaced.

The Other image was of what I'm currently getting.
The date labels are evenly spaced, but the bars are not lined up with the dates.  Some of the bars are closer together then others, and there are more bars then data labels.

Thank you in advance for any advice you have.

-note
The data-sets used are different sources. The fact on the top graph the 19th shows 100% and the bottom 60% is due to the fact one of them comes from production data and the other development environment.

the data set used for the bottom (the report I'm working on) is

start_date------web_percent

2012-11-19------0.6
2012-11-12------0.822222222222222
2012-11-05------0.96
2012-10-29------0.9364
2012-10-22------0.902
2012-10-15------0.889
2012-10-08------0.86888
2012-10-01------0.85
2012-09-24------0.821
2012-09-17------0.83673469
2012-09-12------0.90384615384615
2012-09-04------0.9038461538

(I have attached the picture now that I've made 10 rep)

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what your sample data set looks like? It almost seems there's several data points for 09/16/2012...

Comment: edited main question with data as requested. :)

Comment: how to get two date comparison in report. like FromDate to ToDate.